# ImageProcessing with multiple threshold to binarize phases on skimage.io´s imread()

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

i`m trying to figure out how to binarize a RGB.png file over its histogram intensities.

[Example: smoothed RGB intensities with estimated thresholds for R,G,B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3TEM.png)

This works so far that i can apply thresholding values for one intensity range with the < and > operator using the following code: (also if i wonder why it isn't **img < thres1** for phase1..)

```
from skimage.io import imread
img=imread('example.png')
#intensitys
thres1 = 30
thres2 = 80
#calculate
phase1 = img > thres1
phase3 = img < thres2
```

Now i tried to get just the pixels between intensities **thres1** and **thres2** with several methods e.g.:

```
phase2 = thres1 < img < thres2
#also
phase2 = thres1<img & img < thres2
#and
phase2 = thres1<img
phase2 = thres2>phase2
```

While this operation it gives me the following ValueError:
**The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**
I also tried to handle this case with a.any() and a.all(), whereby i got no helpful results.

Using `phase2 = np.logical_and(thres1 < img,img < thres2)` is falsely including phase3 into phase2;

`phase2 = np.logical_and(thres1 < img,img > thres2)` is falsely including phase1 into phase2.

[Example: plot of generated image arrays for phase2 = np.logical_and(thres1 < img,img > thres2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FZ2Q.png)

Is there a possibility to create pictures, done of more than one thresholding parameter by drawing all pixels between two intensity values?

Comment: Could you add a minimal sample case, say an image array with a shape of `(4,5,3)` and show us the desired output?

Comment: `phase2 = np.logical_and(thres1 < img, img < thres2)` this should work, so please give a repeatable example of why it doesn't

Comment: got it;  `phase2 = ~(np.logical_and(phase1,phase3))`    thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying a lot of things, the inverse operator got it for me.
it seems like this works as

"give me all pixels, not included in phase1,phase3"

`phase2 = ~(np.logical_and(phase1,phase3))`

needing more than 3 phases, i would still not know how to handle this..